# error on react-native run-android while installation , can't run in windows 10

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am currently running Windows 10. I followed all the steps on the documentation regarding android development on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started but got the following error:

[image]

I tried uninstalling and cleaning my installation directories twice, but still it has the same error.

I really want to setup my development environment for React Native, but I don't know what action to do next.

The versions I'm using (latest):
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.56.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT - here's the output of `react-native start`

[image]

Comment: Paste the output for `react-native start`

Comment: @theapache64 see edit above

Comment: Did you the try the instructions shown in the error ?

Comment: @theapache64 I don't have watchman, so option 1 is out. I'm trying out option 2 right now, which is taking time. is it normally this long?

Comment: Depends on your system configuration. Try restarting the system and run `react-native start --reset-cache` (if you have removed the `node_modules` directory, execute `npm install` before it)

Comment: @theapache64 welp still the same error. I'll try the posted answer below

Comment: Did you try creating a new project and `run-android` and `start` it ?

Comment: I believe window 10 + RN .56 have some issues. So you better downgrade. Here is GitHub ticket to track https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug in version 0.56. The "solution" is to find the correct combination of dependencies' versions.
Try this commands one by one correctly ...

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
npm uninstall react-native
npm install --save react-native@0.55.4
react-native run-android
npm install --save babel-core@latest babel-loader@latest
npm uninstall --save babel-preset-react-native
npm install --save babel-preset-react-native@4.0.0
react-native run-android
```

Comment: @LeeMin anytime mate !